# Should I install SQL Server 64 bit or 32 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Sorry if this question is lame.

For production purpose, i wanted to know when to install SQL Server **64 bit** package and when to install **32 bit** package when the client's PC has: -

1. 32 bit OS and 64 bit Processor
2. 64 bit OS and 32 bit Processor

I am just confused what to install when there is a mix and match in bits of OS and processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 32 bit OS and 64 bit Processor

If the OS is 32-bit, then your applications would have to be 32-bit as well.

> 64 bit OS and 32 bit Processor

You cannot install a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit processor, so this isn't relevant

> when to install SQL Server 64 bit package and when to install 32 bit
>   package

SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer a supported platform, and modern, supported versions of SQL Server are only 64-bit, so the question itself is kind of irrelevent - you should not be installing unsupported versions of SQL Server, however, if you are required to:

- On a 32-bit OS, you can only install the 32-bit version of SQL Server.
- If you have a 64-bit OS (by definition on a 64-bit processor) then you should install the 64-bit version of SQL Server to take full advantage of available resources.